# Issue with Changing Background and Folder Icon Colors in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

"I am encountering a strange problem in IntelliJ. After importing a project and attempting to modify the background and folder icon colors, I'm finding that the changes aren't taking effect. Despite trying various themes, the appearance remains unchanged. How can I successfully alter the folder icon color and appearance?"[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icon and folder color in the Project View in IntelliJ IDEA cannot be set directly (e.g., right-clicking to modify properties won't work - there is no "bgcolor" property).

The file color in the Project View tree can be changed through [scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html). Assign different scopes based on the path, then turn on "Settings | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors | Enable file colors" and "Use in project view".